# Get a device's D2D transmission power in SimuLTE

Tags: omnet++

Using the `simuLTE` framework for `omnet++` I am simulating device-to-device (D2D) transmissions.

I can set the transmission power of all devices (`ueD2DTx[0]` and `ueD2DRx[0]`) that transmits over a D2D link like so:

```
*.ue*[*].nic.phy.d2dTxPower = 24.14973348 # 10*LOG10(260)
```

I want to access this value programmatically. I can get a device's `UeInfo` that holds a `double txPwr;` value, which is `0` unfortunately, so not the value I'm looking for.

Then I wanted to access the parameter directly using

```
double txPwr = par("*.ue*[*].nic.phy.d2dTxPower").doubleValue();
```

or

```
double txPwr = par("*.ueD2DTx[0].nic.phy.d2dTxPower").doubleValue();
```

but I get an error telling me this parameter does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the method of class of a simple module one can read parameter using only its name. Therefore inside `LtePhyUeD2D` you can use:

```
double txPwr = par("d2dTxPower").doubleValue();
```

If you want to read this parameter from another module, you has to obtain a pointer to the module first, for example:

```
cModule *mod= getModuleByPath("<root>.ueD2DTx[0].nic.phy");
double txPwr = mod->par("d2dTxPower").doubleValue();
```